# How can I resolve my mileage and CHECK ERROR on my meter?

Tags: hyundai

My car (santro club) is giving check sign on my meter but when I press the accelarator it went away, as i release my foot it comes again. 2ndly, i am using 45/80 R13 tyre size and my mileage is 11km/litre only.what would be the problem?

Kindly guide me.

Comment: Any number of things could cause this problem. Can you have the code scanned to see whats causing the check light?

Comment: What do you mean by check error? What exactly is lighting up?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what specific codes are being thrown, it is difficult to know what might be causing your CEL "Check Engine Light."

I would recommend stopping at your local auto-parts store, who should have the ability to pull these codes for you, for free. While these stock "P" codes don't often tell the whole story, they're very valuable in helping diagnose what may be going on.

This could be the O2 sensor, the MAF sensor, or something else entirely. The fact that the CEL leaves when you accelerate is concerning, as typically codes thrown from a sensor will stay on until cleared. 
It could be something faulty with the diagnostic system itself, but at that point I'm just speculating - the bottom line is, you need to figure out what "code" is causing the CEL to properly diagnose it.
If you don't have a local shop who can read the codes, you can also pick up a code-scanning tool inexpensively online, or through a local auto-parts store. The standard OBD-II scanners are the least expensive, but will not read/clear factory specific codes (they will typically only read the default "P" codes).

As for your mileage, are you running the stock tire size?
The Santro Club OE tire size is 155/70/R13 [according to the spec-sheet](http://www.pakwheels.com/new-cars/hyundai/santro/club/specifications/).
You mentioned running size 45/80/R13 tires - is it possible that you meant 145/80? If so, you may be running the incorrect tire size which would affect how many miles your car thinks it is going, and would thereby also mess up its fuel consumption calculations (as well as your odometer reading and speed).

Comment: Yes it is 145/80/R13. Actually shop keeper said if you will use 145/80 then, your mileage will be more good but there is no difference from the previous one. Last time i was using 165/65.

Comment: Changing tire size could potentially change actual mileage if you're adding or reducing significant mass/weight, and making it harder/easier for the engine to push tires. This is more of a concern with SUVs and larger trucks which might jump up several tire sizes (i.e., my jeep has 35" tires which weigh a lot more than stock). Still, if the car's computer thinks it's pushing a different sized tire than it actually is, its mileage calculations will be off, so I would check your mileage "manually," by tracking 2-3 filling cycles and carefully calculating how much you're putting in.